# How to programatically find files in a folder

Tags: magento2, cron, file

I am creating a **cron job** for a **Magento 2 site**. This cron job will search for files in

> /var/custom_folder/

and will then process them.

I already have the cron job setup and can handle processing the file but I am wondering if there are any **tools/libraries in magento 2** that can help with this process of finding files.

It is possible to do this without magento just using straight **PHP commands** but I am wondering if Magento has any tools that could help this process.

Part of the task that I will need to do when detecting these files is handle where they go as they are named in a certain format:

**"part1-typeb-****.csv"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `glob` Function It'll help you to find a file in the folder. Check code for your reference.

```
$directory = "var/mycsv";
$csvs = glob($directory . "xyz.csv");

foreach($csvs as $csv)
{
  echo $csv;
}
```

I hope it'll help you. :)

Comment: Great, its work for me. Thanks **@Mayank**

Comment: FYI, there exists a wrapper for the glob function in M2 : `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Glob`. Cheers

Comment: I had to get the (media) directory like: $directory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath() . "example/folder/structure/";